# Python Tkinter error, cannot access local variable 'df' where it is not associated with a value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tkinter, openpyxl

I am trying to use Tkinter Python to create an interface to browse and display excel tables, but I am having troubles in the open file part (bold), I get the error message from the headline. In the code down below the bold parts are the function/command, the buttom and the tree view. Thoughts on what the problem is?

```
`import tkinter as tk
import sv_ttk, numpy
from tkinter import ttk, font, Checkbutton, filedialog, messagebox
import TKinterModernThemes as TKMT
from tkinter import*
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl

raiz=Tk()
font.families()

raiz.title("Wind Analysis")

raiz.iconbitmap(r'C:\Users\osori\Downloads\renewable-energy-icon.ico')
#raiz.geometry('800x520')
#raiz.config(bg="#69F5B9")
sv_ttk.set_theme("dark")
**def upload_file():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfile(title='Abrir Archivo', 
                                      filetypes=[('Excel file', '.xlsx')])
    if filename:
        try:
            filename = r"{}".format(filename)
            df = pd.read_excel(filename)
            
        except:
            messagebox.showerror('Error', 'No tiene Acceso al Documento')

    tree.delete(*tree.get_children())
    tree['column'] = list(df.columns)
    tree['show'] = "headings"
    for col in tree['column']:
        tree.heading(col,text=col)

    df_rows = df.to_numpy().tolist()
    for row in df_rows:
        tree.insert("","end", values=row)
        tree.pack()**
```

Comment: Can you please try to reduce the amount of code a bit? It seems like there are more widgets than necessary to reproduce the proble. See [mcve] for more help. Also, please include the full error traceback.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: **Note** Using two asterisk to bold text doesn't work in formatted code, so where you have added these in your code sample they will remain as  `**`. You'd be better off to use comments to indicate the 'bold' areas you want to highlight in your code.

Comment: Use `askopenfilename()` instead of `askopenfile()` if you just want the filename.  Also you should put those lines (starting from `tree.delete(...)` to end of function) after `df = pd.read_excel(filename)` because `df` may not be defined in case there is exception. Also better to show the exception message instead of custom message because you can see what is the error actually.

Answer (score 0):

Where you open the Excel file

```
filename = filedialog.askopenfile(title='Abrir Archivo', 
                                  filetypes=[('Excel file', '.xlsx')])
```

you are creating a textio wrapper, so when you create the dataframe

```
df = pd.read_excel(filename)
```

it will hit the exception.
Try setting the mode to open the file to "bytes mode"

```
filename = filedialog.askopenfile(title='Abrir Archivo',
                                  mode=rb,  # Set the mode
                                  filetypes=[('Excel file', '.xlsx')])
```

Comment: It won't solve the issue if the line `filename = r"{}".format(filename)` is not removed because it converts the file object `filename` to string and using this in `pd.read_excel(filename)` will raise exception.

Comment: Yep you're right, I did disable that line in my check and then forgot to mention it in the answer